# Can't rest thumb on trackpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, 15.10

**Laptop:** Lenovo Y-40-80

So, I recently installed Ubuntu 15.10. Now, I've come from Windows 10 so I'm use to resting my thumb on the left button while moving the mouse, only this isn't working in Ubuntu...

People have asked similar questions but with no real solution. I'm also unable to install the package xorg, even on adding the repository.

Anybody know a fix for this?

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what your problem is? I'm not sure I understand. Are you talking about physical seperate buttons or buttons that are integrated in the trackpad area?

Comment: Also: don't try to install xorg. It's already installed. It's the garphical system that makes stuff appear on your screen. ;)

Comment: I'm talking about the physical separate buttons. I often, while using my trackpad, rest my thumb on the left click button, just so it's easier to click. Basically, my index finger is moving the mouse and my thumb is just resting on the left-click. But when I do that in Ubuntu, the mouse doesn't move.

Comment: That's extremely strange. Maybe try to figure out the touchpad make and search for that. [This](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) might help getting the needed info.